# htaccess conditional header set is ignoring the condition

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http-headers, cors

I'm trying to set headers if the origin is a particular site to solve a resource conflict I'm having (using Mautic hosted on a subdomain).

If I add the headers for any situation I get a 500 error when I try to use Mautic, but the resource being accessed from my site works, hence I only want to set them when my site is the origin.

This is what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
#preserve HTTP(S)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIfNoCase Origin %{ENV:proto}://mysite.com ENV_SET
    SetEnvIfNoCase Origin %{ENV:proto}://mautic.mysite.com ENV_SET=0
    Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{ENV:proto}://mysite.com env=ENV_SET
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true env=ENV_SET
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, OPTIONS env=ENV_SET
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token env=ENV_SET
</IfModule>
```

As far as I understood that would make the headers set conditionally on existence of the environment variable, but they're being set no matter what. If I remove the SetEnvIf lines they're still set. I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270902/set-apache-headers-conditionally) which suggests that it should be placed in configuration instead of .htaccess, but I'm not sure what that means.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this, or another way to make it work?

Thanks

EDIT: syntax updated with advice from w3dk, now looks like

```
    SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "%{ENV:proto}://mysite.com" ENV_SET
    SetEnvIfNoCase Origin "%{ENV:proto}://mautic.mysite.com" !ENV_SET
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "%{ENV:proto}://mysite.com" env=ENV_SET
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true" env=ENV_SET
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, OPTIONS" env=ENV_SET
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token" env=ENV_SET
```

EDIT 2: Turns out it doesn't like the %{ENV:proto} part, so I've changed that to http and added another line for https. The subdomain is working fine and the headers are setting, except that I'm getting 'Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header is 'true, true'.' in the console. It's only being set once (I also tried 'merge', and I'm using set for the Allow-Origin; I can't figure out where else this would be set.

Comment: Ah yes, the `%{ENV:proto}` server/environment variable is not expanded since that argument is a regex, not an ordinary string. What do you mean by "Credentials flag is 'true'" - what _flag_ is that (or are you referring to the `Access.....Credentials` header)? If you are getting the header value `true, true` then that would seem to imply a `merge` header _somewhere_?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the Access...Credentials header. From what I've read it's an error that happens if it's set twice, but I don't understand how it's working here. It works fine if I set it without the env=ENV_SET.  It doesn't work with that, even if I use merge instead of set.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, OPTIONS env=ENV_SET
> ```

If the *value* contains spaces then it should be surrounded in double quotes. Probably safer to *always* enclose the value in quotes. You should also omit the `:` at the end of the header name. So, for example:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, OPTIONS" env=ENV_SET
```

> ```
> SetEnvIfNoCase Origin %{ENV:proto}://mautic.mysite.com ENV_SET=0
> ```

**UPDATE:** The third argument to `SetEnvIf[NoCase]` is a regex, so *server variables* (ie. `%{ENV:proto}` are not expanded - they will be matched literally. If you need to match either `http` or `https` then build that into a single regex, eg. `https?` (The `?` makes the previous character optional). (However, your site should be either one or the other, not both?)

To *unset*/remove an environment variable, you should prefix it with an `!` (exclamation mark) rather than set it to `0` (this is still set). For example:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Origin https?://mautic.mysite.com !ENV_SET
```

> If I remove the SetEnvIf lines they're still set.

Probably because of failing to quote the header *value*. But this could also be a caching issue - so make sure all caches are cleared.

> ...it should be placed in configuration instead of .htaccess

By "configuration" they are probably referring to the *server config*. This would be preferable (and disable the use of `.htaccess` files). However, it's not the cause of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've seen so many variations in syntax I haven't known what's what. Sadly, with the changes I'm still getting the 500 error. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you are getting 500s then first thing to do is check the error log, you can then add any relevant entries to your question.

Comment: Ah, of course. Will do.